# Java Hibernate database doesn't automatically insert timestamp in MySQL database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

So this is my current Java Hibernate code, this table is part of a database that is supposed to store temperature values

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Data
public class TempTable { //Den viktigaste tabellen i DBMS, här lagras data rått
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;

    private Float temperatures;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    @CreationTimestamp
    @LastModifiedBy
    private LocalDateTime timestamp; // ' 2023-09-24T12:34:56.789 '

    @Transient
    public String getFormattedTimestamp(){ //Denna metod påverkar inte data som finns i tabellerna, den är framtagen för enkelt kunna formatera data
        if (timestamp != null) {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd 'hour' HH : 'minute' mm : 'seconds' : ss.SSS");
            return timestamp.format(formatter);
        }
        System.out.println("Could not format datetime");
        return "";
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tempTable", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<WarningTable> warningTables = new ArrayList<>();

    public TempTable(Long Id, Float temperatures, LocalDateTime timestamp){
        this.Id = Id;
        this.temperatures = temperatures;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(LocalDateTime timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

}
```

This is really where I think the main issue is, either I'm using the wrong annotations or I don't know what I talking about, I have some getters and setters. But I don't think i'll use them for now

```
@Column(name = "timestamp")
@CreationTimestamp
@LastModifiedBy
private LocalDateTime timestamp; // ' 2023-09-24T12:34:56.789 '
```

And simply doing this in MySQL workbench:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table (temperatures) VALUES (22.5);
INSERT INTO temp_table (temperatures) VALUES (32.5);
INSERT INTO temp_table (temperatures) VALUES (21.5);
```

Should automatically just set the timestamp in the database. But when I through my endpoint request with JSON this is what it returns:

```
  {
    "temperatures": 22.5,
    "timestamp": null,
    "warningTables": [],
    "id": 1,
    "formattedTimestamp": ""
  },
  {
    "temperatures": 32.5,
    "timestamp": null,
    "warningTables": [],
    "id": 2,
    "formattedTimestamp": ""
  },
  {
    "temperatures": 21.5,
    "timestamp": null,
    "warningTables": [],
    "id": 3,
    "formattedTimestamp": ""
  }
]
```

Why is timestamp null? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It will be null forever il you will insert the values from workbench, because these two annotations are from ORM(hibernate)

```
@CreationTimestamp
@LastModifiedBy
```

To have these columns populate with values into database the insert request should be passed through hibernate

As solution, to have a inserted/updated time of the entity when the values are populated you can create a trigger on table something like in this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988885/trigger-on-insert-and-update-that-adds-modification-date). Also don't forget to remove
`@CreationTimestamp`,`@LastModifiedBy` if you will choose to do it with trigger.

Comment: Thank you, how do I do this through java hibernate tho?

Comment: This responsibility will be on database side, I mean every insert/update doesn’t matter from application(Java,hibernate) or workbench will have update time field populate, trigger will do it.

Comment: If you find my answer really helpfully, don't forget to upvote and approve it

Comment: Any updates about it ?

Comment: Thank for the help, but it wasn't applicable in my case.
I just told my co-workers they will have to insert timestamp manually

The purpose of my code was that all the changes that affect the database's behavior should be done through my java application and not through workbench or similiar tools.

Comment: I get you, by the way this was the reason why you were not able to got the create timestamp and I think that you should approve this answer for others people to know that is the right way.

Comment: The question was `Why the timestamp is not inserting automatically when i do inserts by workbench`

Comment: Also i wrote about it `To have these columns populate with values into database the insert request should be passed through hibernate(java application)`